# Access process memory directly

Tags: c, memory-management, virtual-memory

simple question:

Is it possible, and how is it possible, to acess the Virtual Memory of my program directly?

To be specific,
instead of typing

```
int someValue = 5;
```

can I do something like this:

```
VirtualMemory[0x0] = (int)5;
```

I'm just asking because I want the values to be stored next to each other to get a nice and small memory map.

When I look into assembler basics, the processor stores values directly after each other and I was wondering how to do so in c.

Thanks for all of your replies.

Cheers,

Lucky

Comment: Just place the values in an array, which is always continuous in memory, what does virtual memory have to do with it?

Comment: What OS/platform is this?  Your program is already running in a virtual memory space on Windows/unix.  If you want values stored "next to each other" then just use an array or a chunk of memory from malloc()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly, because in the source code you don't know which memory address your program is going to be "loaded into".  So all memory addresses in the program are encoded in an "offset from the start of program" type manner.

Part of the "process loader"'s responsibility in copying the program into memory is to add the "base offset pointer" to all the other offesets, so all the "names" describing memory addresses refer to actual memory addresses instead of "offsets from the beginning of the program".

That's generally a good thing, as if they were encoded directly, two programs that needed the same set of addresses couldn't be run at the same time without corrupting each other's shared memory.  In addition, loading a program into a different starting address would not be possible, as walking outside of the memory of your program (nearly guaranteed if you relocate the program without rewriting the memory address references) is going to raise a segfault in the operating system's memory management monitors.

Also you need a name to start at, and this means that the offsets are bound to the variable names.  Generally it is much easier to do fishing around in the heap based off of an alloc'd item than it is to truly find the start of the program loaded in memory (because the C programming language doesn't really capture that address into a in-language variable name, and the layout is somewhat system dependent).